# get Null pointer Exception when try to access model class in dwr function

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
    My SessionFactory object is @Autowired

    package com.ravi.dao.daoImpl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.ravi.dao.UserDao;
    import com.ravi.model.User;

    @Repository("userDao")
    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<User> listUsers() 
        {
            System.out.println("UserDaoImpl - listUsers");
            return (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).list();
        }
        @Override
        public void saveUser(User user) 
        {
            System.out.println("UserDaoImpl - saveUser");
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<User> getUserByUserEmail(String userEmail) 
        {
            System.out.println("UserDaoImpl - getUserByUserEmail");
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where userEmail=:userEmail").setString("userEmail",userEmail).list();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<User> validateLoginUser(String userEmail, String password) 
        {
            System.out.println("userEmail -- "+userEmail+" password --"+password);
            System.out.println("UserDaoImpl - validateLoginUser");
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where userEmail=:userEmail and password=:password").setString("userEmail", userEmail).setString("password",password).list();
        }
    }


    i create on dwr function which is below.

    package com.ravi.dwr;

    import java.util.List;
    import com.ravi.dao.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl;
    import com.ravi.model.User;


    public class ForgotPwd 
    {
        public void sendMail(String EmailId)
        {
            System.out.println("DWR Called.");

            UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl=new UserDaoImpl();
            List<User> lstUser=userDaoImpl.getUserByUserEmail(EmailId);
            User user=lstUser.get(0);

            System.out.println("DWR Called.-- userEmail :"+user.getUserEmail());    
        }
    }
    when i want to try to print userEmail . null pointer exception is generated @ return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where userEmail=:userEmail").setString("userEmail",userEmail).list(); this point.


    my spring-servlet.xml cofiguration.


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ravi"/>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <!--  <bean id="sessionFactory"  -->
    <!--            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> -->
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.ravi.model.User</value>
                    <value>com.ravi.model.Language</value>
                    <value>com.ravi.model.Questions</value>
                    <value>com.ravi.model.QuestionOptions</value>
                    <value>com.ravi.model.Admin</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="SessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
        </bean>

    in my project i used Annotation. is there any way to get user model data in dwr function.
    or is there any process which automatically initialized (inject) when i try to use DAO class)

     i don't want to remove @Autowired annotation in sessionFactory object. so please suggest me the best way to access or configure dwr function. other way i tried without using @Autowired annotation but in that case i have to entry all bean class in my spring-servlet.xml and also configure. hibernate.cfg.xml file.

 in my project i used Annotation. is there any way to get user model data in dwr function.
    or is there any process which automatically initialized (inject) when i try to use DAO class)


   here i explain whole process. thank you in advance.
   below error is generated when i am try to access userDaoImpl function. it is error show that session factory object is not initialized.
    on more time i cleared that this is DWR function. which try to access sessionFactory instance. 
without interacting controller.


UserLoginController --> showUserLogin 
INFO   (org.directwebremoting.log.startup:157) - Starting: DwrServlet v3.0.0-RC2-final-312 on Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 / JDK 1.7.0_10 from Oracle Corporation at `enter code here`/OnlineQuestion
DWR Called.
INFO   (org.directwebremoting.log.accessLog:427) - Method execution failed: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ravi.dwr.ForgotPwd.sendMail(ForgotPwd.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule$1.doFilter(CreatorModule.java:229)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule.executeMethod(CreatorModule.java:241)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:379)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:332)
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:104)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChai
```

here i explain whole process. thank you in advance.
       below error is generated when i am try to access userDaoImpl function. it is error show that session factory object is not initialized.
        on more time i cleared that this is DWR function. which try to access sessionFactory instance. 
    without interacting controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use Spring MVC with DWR, try following code:

WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  ...
  xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
  ...
  http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
  http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">
  <dwr:controller id="dwrController" />
  <dwr:annotation-scan base-package="com.ravi.dwr" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
    <property name="mappings">
      <props>
        <prop key="/dwr/**/*">dwrController</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.ravi" />
  ...

</beans>
```

ForgotPwd.java

```
package com.ravi.dwr;

...
import org.directwebremoting.annotations.RemoteMethod;
import org.directwebremoting.annotations.RemoteProxy;
...

@RemoteProxy
public class ForgotPwd {

  @Autowired
  private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;

  ...

  @RemoteMethod
  public void sendMail(String EmailId) {
    System.out.println("DWR Called.");
    List<User> lstUser=userDaoImpl.getUserByUserEmail(EmailId);
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: main problem here is that sessionFactory instance is not initialized when i try to access it from dwr function. is there any other option than suggest me.

Comment: How do you get the ForgotPwd instance?

Comment: There is one jsp page. in that page i have link script - dwr function dwr/instance/ForgotPwd.js than call function ForgotPwd.sendMail($("#emailId).val()); it works and also value passed in function but when i tried to call userDaoImpl.getUserByEmail than get Error null pointer

Comment: If you want to use DWR with Spring, you need to use `DispatcherServlet`(Spring MVC) or `DwrSpringServlet`. See [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/spring.html) and [here](http://www.butterdev.com/dwr/2009/12/dwr-3-x-and-spring/).

Comment: yes man i know that, already configure that, without DispatcherServlet and DWR.xml eclipse does not allow to call dwr function so in my case dwr function called successfully. you didn't get the proper question. please read question again. my problem is i have configure userDaoImpl Repository and sessionFactory object is Autowire when request comes from controller than sessionFactory object successfully injected but when i tried to access it from dwr function which directly call getUserByEmail() funciton. at that time i got null pointer exception.

Comment: if you want to source code than give me your mail id . will send you.

Comment: `at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)` According to the stacktrace, you are using `DwrServlet`. Try using `DwrSpringServlet` instead of `DwrServlet`.

Comment: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Comment: in web.xml i define org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrSpringServlet above exception is generated and my dwr Function not called.

Comment: I have read your question again and updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. i am still getting same error. and in this case org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrSpringServlet is not working.

Comment: Do you have any dwr+spring mvc example which is used spring annotation and sessionFactory instance has been @Autowire. than send.

Comment: <dwr:controller id="dwrController" /> is not working in spring-servlet.xml

Comment: I have created a working example. See [here](https://github.com/snicki0201/dwr-spring-intergration).